# ffmpeg: white padding is light grey but not white

Tags: ffmpeg, color

I want to generate 16:9 thumbnails from videos with white padding but the resulting picture has grey padding instead of white. This is the command line (input here is a jpg but the effect is the same when using a video):

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "https://gooseberry.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/franck.jpg" -filter_complex scale=iw*min(852/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(852/iw\,480/ih),pad=852:480:(852-iw*min(852/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(852/iw\,480/ih))/2:white,fps=fps=50/5.000000 output.jpg
```

the resulting image (text and white box added with paint): 
[image]

even though the padding color is white it's light grey in reality. Is there a way to get it 'whiter'? It's especially ugly if you plan to print it on paper.

Comment: Please show the complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: The padding is RGB 235, which is the upper limit in conventional video. So, a video player will expand 235 to show white.

Comment: @mulvya that's great for conventional video but not if you plan to print it. Any way to override this

Comment: Outputting to PNG will get you pure white. Then using ffmpeg again to convert to JPG preserves the values.

Comment: So, first ffmpeg.exe -i franck.jpg -filter_complex "scale=iw*min(852/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(852/iw\,480/ih),pad=852:480:(852-iw*min(852/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(852/iw\,480/ih))/2:white,fps=fps=50/5.000000 franck-padded.png

Comment: Then ffmpeg -i franck-padded.png franck-padded.jpg

Comment: That's a nice workaround. Thank you. Nevertheless I prefer a direct way so I don't lose time unnecessarily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The end of the filter chain should output full RGB, like this:

Windows batch:

```bash
ffmpeg.exe -i "https://gooseberry.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/franck.jpg" ^
  -filter_complex ^
   scale=iw*min(852/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(852/iw\,480/ih),^
pad=852:480:(852-iw*min(852/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(852/iw\,480/ih))/2:white,^
format=rgb24 franck-padded.jpg
```

Linux bash:

```bash
ffmpeg -i "https://gooseberry.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/franck.jpg" \
  -filter_complex \
   "scale=iw*min(852/iw\,480/ih):ih*min(852/iw\,480/ih),\
pad=852:480:(852-iw*min(852/iw\,480/ih))/2:(480-ih*min(852/iw\,480/ih))/2:white,\
format=rgb24" franck-padded.jpg
```

The important part is **format=rgb24** which keeps or converts the final filter output to the RGB pixel format, which allows full range values from 0-255. Without that final filter, ffmpeg will convert the filter output to the YUV pixel format where the range of legal values is 16 to 235 for luma (brightness) - 16 maps to black and 235 to white - and 16 to 240 for the chroma components (color). (The default YUV [colorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) range is a legacy of analog television signals and carried over into the digital realm by the MPEG committee and hence still widely adhered to by most digital video formats)

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Still get grey color.

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input.png -vf "pad=iw+0:ih+300:0:300:#FFFFFF@1,format=rgb24" -y output.png`

Comment: Don't see anything wrong. How are you checking the output?

Comment: I open the output in both Chrome and Preview on Mac and I confirm that the color is grey instead of white. FFmpeg is based on an old version (2015-02), I will try the latest version soon.

Comment: I tried the version downloaded here: http://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  and it gave me white color even without `format=rgb24`!

Comment: For PNG, that will be the case.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to put the `format=rgb24` at the beginning of the filter chain, not the end.

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me. I find a work around to this problem. PNG images doesn't have this issue. So you could first convert the file into PNG, then do the padding and convert it back to original image type. Let's say you have a file named `input.jpeg`, try something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpeg -y temp.png
ffmpeg -i temp.png -vf "pad=iw+0:ih+300:0:300:#FFFFFF@1" -y output.jpeg
```